# Linq C# select item from collection of types

Tags: c#, linq

I have observablecollection of types and in many place's it need's to remove some element that have condition for example "number==2". But it have many weak places when it can crash. How to improve code? Write some extension method that will check conditions "if(temp!=null)", or?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
public class DataStruct
{
    public int number { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObservableCollection<DataStruct> Test = new ObservableCollection<DataStruct>();
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            Test.Add(new DataStruct { number=i});
        }
        DataStruct temp = Test.Where(k => k.number ==2).FirstOrDefault();
        if (temp != null)
        {
            int index = Test.IndexOf(Test.Where(k => k.number == 2).FirstOrDefault());
            try
            {
                Test.Remove(Test[index]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        foreach (DataStruct item in Test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.number);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create extension method to do that everything. Example:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static DataStruct Filter(this IEnumerable<DataStruct> collection) {
        if (collection == null) {
            return null; // or throw if you like
        }
        return collection
            .Where(k => k.number ==2)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Test.Filter()
```

But you can also create method such as `EmptyIfNull`:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static DataStruct EmptyIfNull(this IEnumerable<DataStruct> collection) {
        if (collection == null) {
            return return new DataStruct[0];
        }
        return collection;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Test.EmptyIfNull().Where(k => k.number ==2).FirstOrDefault();
```